# Generating a list from items stored in a (My)SQL table

Tags: mysql, list

Can I generate a list in varchar() form - like **'London; Paris; New York'** - from a MySQL table that contains the list in the form

```
<code> 
List_Id Order Value
1       1     London
1       2     Paris
1       3     New York
</code>
```

using only a SQL statement ? Or is this possible only **outside** MySQL, e.g. in PHP ?

Comment: `select concat('<li>', \`Value\`, '</li>') from yourtable order by \`Order\``

Comment: Of course you can. But personally I think it's better to use application level code if that's available- unless you also happen to be performing  other aggregate operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose you can use [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). In the example, its first parameter is the field you want to use, its second parameter is the separator you indicated you want.

```
select group_concat(Value, '; ')
from yourtable
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it.

Comment: Sure, but... how do I do that ? I see no appropriate button.

Comment: @Mikey, there is a number shown to the left in my answer. Below that there is a grey checkbox. By clicking on that checkbox you accept the answer.